# IndentationError in the Following Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def revisedRussianRoulette(doors):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(doors), 2):
        i = int(i)
        if doors[i] == 1 & counter == 0:
            counter += 1
        elif doors[i] == 1 & counter == 1:
            doors[i] = 0
            doors[i-2] = 0
            doors[i+2] = 0
        elif doors[i] == 0 & counter == 1:
            doors[i-2] = 0
    return doors


n = int(input().strip())
doors = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
result = revisedRussianRoulette(doors)
print (" ".join(map(str, result)))
```

I think it should be properly indented, but I get an error that says:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Practice Files>2nd_answer_week_of_code_36.py
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\PracticeFiles\2nd_answer_week_of_code_36.py", line 13
return doors
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: do indent in `elif` both `elif` should be inside for loop

Comment: also, the `counter += 1` line is not indented 1 level extra from the preceding `if`

Comment: I have updated the question. This is my current code. That was poor formatting earlier. First question of mine on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do indenation like this :

```
def revisedRussianRoulette(doors):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(doors), 2):
        i = int(i)
        if doors[i] == 1 & counter == 0:
            counter += 1
        elif doors[i] == 1 & counter == 1:
            doors[i] = 0
            doors[i-2] = 0
            doors[i+2] = 0
        elif doors[i] == 0 & counter == 1:
            doors[i-2] = 0
    return doors
```

Comment: That was an error in the question. I have updated the question.

Comment: No, I have updated the question. This is my current code. Still the same error. I don’t know why?

Comment: @oATOMo can you trace back your current error, When I try code i don't get any error .

Comment: What do u mean by trace Back?

Comment: @VikasDamodar do you use 6 spaces for indendation? If I copy your code, that is at least. Never seen that before, I think standard is four.

Comment: I used four spaces only in my actual code. Here to write my code I used this formatting.

Comment: @VikasDamodar how do you do that? This is the full error I am getting.

Comment: @Banana yeah standard is 4, maybe its six, I will check it, But if it is six also doesn't give indentation error.

Comment: @VikasDamodar well, it does usually

Comment: Please someone give me a final solution

Comment: @oATOMo you can check your code here, I dont find any error, : https://repl.it/repls/UnrealisticDevotedMuskox

Comment: Thanks Vikas for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
def revisedRussianRoulette(doors):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(doors), 2):
        i = int(i)
        condition_one = doors[i] == 1 & counter == 0
        condition_two = doors[i] == 1 & counter == 1
        condition_three = doors[i] == 0 & counter == 1
        if condition_one:
            counter += 1
        elif condition_two:
            doors[i] = 0
            doors[i-2] = 0
            doors[i+2] = 0
        elif condition_three:
            doors[i-2] = 0
        return doors

n = int(input().strip())
doors = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
result = revisedRussianRoulette(doors)
print (" ".join(map(str, result)))
```

Comment: What difference does it make?